# sbt-android gives "IllegalArgumentException already added..." running android:package for multi-project build

Tags: sbt-android

I have an sbt `root` project with an `actionbarsherlock` subproject which I can't package into an apk.

I am able to build both projects successfully, but when I run `android:package` I get errors from the `root/android:dex` task where classes from actionbarsherlock are being dex'd twice:

```
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/ActionBarSherlock$Implementation;
```

I ran `last root/android:dex` and found that it is including the `intermediates/class.jar` from both the root project as well as the subproject:

```
.../actionbarsherlock/bin/intermediates/classes.jar,
.../bin/intermediates/classes.jar
```

That explains the dex error but I don't know how to change my build to avoid that.

I was able to replicate this issue on a much simpler project where the root project has no source and a simple build config like:

```
// build.sbt for root
androidBuild

javacOptions in Compile ++= "-source" :: "1.7" :: "-target" :: "1.7" :: Nil

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(abs)

lazy val abs = project.in(file("actionbarsherlock"))
```

and:

```
// build.sbt for subproject
androidBuild

javacOptions in Compile ++= "-source" :: "1.7" :: "-target" :: "1.7" :: Nil

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.android.support" % "support-v4" % "18.0.0"
)
```

Both projects have `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```

and `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-android" % "sbt-android" % "1.6.0")
```

The file hierarchy looks like:

```
.
├── actionbarsherlock
│   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── lint.xml
│   ├── project
│   │   ├── build.properties
│   │   └── plugins.sbt
│   ├── project.properties
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── res
│       ├── ...
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── test
│       └── ...
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── build.sbt
├── lint.xml
├── proguard-project.txt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── plugins.sbt
├── project.properties
├── README.MD
├── res
│   ├── ...
├── src
```

The typical process I have been using on sbt from a clean checkout is:

```
project abs
compile
project root
compile
android:package
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Including both jar files is not indicative of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the reference to actionbarsherlock in `project.properties`.  The actionbarsherlock project is automatically built because it is in `project.properties`, it is duplicated because you added a manual subproject.

Everything would have just worked if you never setup all the sbt project stuff in the actionbarsherlock project. Given that you did set it up, you did not make proper use of the `androidBuildWith` function for dependent projects. Remove the `androidBuild` line from the root project and change the root project in line to `project.in(file(".")).androidBuildWith(abs)`

Also, consider using the actionbarsherlock apklib rather than a subproject. On top of that, move away from actionbarsherlock altogether.

Additionally, you can build fully by just running `sbt android:package` from a clean build. No need for all those steps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up removing the build definitions from the actionbarsherlock project as that seemed to be what you thought was the more straightforward solution